# Add text to website when RSS feed number equals zero

Tags: java, php, html, css, rss

How can I add text to our site (http://www.climatescience.cam.ac.uk/) when an RSS feed has zero items?

e.g., when there are no talks scheduled then display the text "no talks currently scheduled"

Comment: This should not be tagged html or css. Probably should only have php OR java too.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the RSS items being fed from? Can you access the same database yourself?

Or - can you use cUrl to read the RSS feed and detect when there are no recent items?

Comment: The RSS items are coming from http://talks.cam.ac.uk/show/rss/31749.  I don't have access to the database where the RSS feeds are generated.  Good idea about using cURL, if there is no cleaner way to do this I'll setup a cron job to check the RSS feed and edit the html file accordingly.

Comment: Why not use the cron to store the current size of the feed in your database then query the database on your page?